# Check is string has been formatted using a certain template

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

What i'm trying to check in C#, is for instance:

if **name_Ford_value_Focus** (good)

or

**name_value_Focus** (bad)

conforms to the template

"**name_{0}_value{1}**"

Do I have to use regex's?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to match the complete string (if not then remove ^ and $ from pattern to match within a string)...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^name_.+_value_.+$";
        Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match( "name_Ford_value_Focus", pattern ).Success.ToString() );//true
        Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match( "name_value_Focus", pattern ).Success.ToString() );//false
        //Other examples:
        Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match( "name_Toyota_value_Corolla", pattern ).Success.ToString() );//true
        Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match( "name_Mini_value_", pattern ).Success.ToString() );//false
        Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match( "Applename_Ford_value_FocusApple", pattern ).Success.ToString() );//false because full string match. Remove ^ and $ from pattern for true

    }
}
```

where:

- ^ means 'starts with'. $ means 'ends with'. Together they mean match the full string.
- . means match a character.
- + means 1 or more characters.